# Navigation drawer menu items shows old locale values

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am facing a weird issue with navigation drawer items,
I have 3 different string resources for 3 languages and on recreating activity on a button click all the texts in activity changes to respective language except the navigation drawer items, but on the next recreation drawer items changes and shows the values which it should have shown previously, so its one step late.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (Constants.language==2) {
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "ur");
    }else if (Constants.language==1){
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "hi");
    }else if (Constants.language==0){
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "en");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.nav_language) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_language));
        builder.setPositiveButton("hindi",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Constants.language = 1;
                        dialog.cancel();
                        recreate();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNeutralButton("english",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Constants.language = 0;
                        dialog.cancel();
                        recreate();
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("urdu",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Constants.language = 2;
                        dialog.cancel();
                        recreate();
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }




    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_topstories"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_top_stories"
        android:title="@string/top_stories" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_india"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_india"
        android:title="@string/india" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_world"
        android:icon="@drawable/world_icon"
        android:title="@string/world" />
</group>
</menu>
```

I have checked everything else like locale,constant.language and the strings for all 3 languages, other textviews in the activity are being updated properly only the drawer sync is delayed by 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone faces the same issue, this is what i did to solve it

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear();
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
```

i think even on activity recreate the resources are not reloaded so clearing it and inflating it again solves it.

Comment: Can you add some resolved reference for your answer?

Comment: no its not work

Answer (score 3):

You have to change/load the language before calling setContentView(). This applies to views that use the menu resource: eg. bottomNavigationView, NavigationDrawer. If you change/Load after setContentView() it won't change the above-mentioned views unless you recreated the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        changeLanguage(getBaseContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeLanguage(Context context, String languageToload) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToload);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is LanguageChanger?

Comment: It was a single custom that contains changeLanguage method. I removed it now for simplicity